# Cobol: Statement not Ended by End Perform When End Perform is Present

Tags: cobol

Taking a class on Cobol and having issues getting a program to run. I'm using opencobol to run through command prompt. The program is:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. SAMPLE.
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
          SELECT EMPLOYEE-DATA
             ASSIGN TO "C:\COBOL\EMPLOYEE-INFO.DAT"
             ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
          SELECT PAYROLL-LISTING
             ASSIGN TO "C:\COBOL\PAYROLL-OUT.DAT"
             ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
       DATA DIVISION.
       FILE SECTION.
       FD  EMPLOYEE-DATA.
       01  EMPLOYEE-RECORD.
           05  EMPLOYEE-NAME-IN      PICTURE X(20).
           05  HOURS-WORKED-IN       PICTURE 9(2).
           05  HOURLY-RATE-IN        PICTURE 9V99.
       FD  PAYROLL-LISTING.
       01  PRINT-REC.
           05                        PICTURE X(20).
           05  NAME-OUT              PICTURE X(20).
           05                        PICTURE X(10).
           05  HOURS-OUT             PICTURE 9(2).
           05                        PICTURE X(8).
           05  RATE-OUT              PICTURE 9.99.
           05                        PICTURE X(6).
           05  WEEKLY-WAGES-OUT      PICTURE 999.99.
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01  ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS    PICTURE XXX VALUE 'YES'.
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       100-MAIN-MODULE.
           OPEN INPUT EMPLOYEE-DATA
                OUTPUT PAYROLL-LISTING
           PERFORM UNTIL ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS = 'NO '
               READ EMPLOYEE-DATA
                    AT END
                         MOVE 'NO ' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS
                    NOT AT END
                         PERFORM 200-WAGE-ROUTINE
               END READ
           END PERFORM
           CLOSE EMPLOYEE-DATA
                 PAYROLL-LISTING
           STOP RUN.
       200-WAGE-ROUTINE.
           MOVE SPACES TO PRINT-REC
           MOVE EMPLOYEE-NAME-IN TO NAME-OUT
           MOVE HOURS-WORKED-IN TO HOURS-OUT
           MOVE HOURLY-RATE-IN TO RATE-OUT
           MULTIPLY HOURS-WORKED-IN BY HOURLY-RATE-IN
                    GIVING WEEKLY-WAGES-OUT
           WRITE PRINT-REC.
           STOP RUN.
```

When running the program I'm getting the following error:

```
Sample.cob: In paragraph '100-MAIN-MODULE':
Sample.cob:35: Error: PERFORM statement not terminated by END-PERFORM
Sample.cob:41: Error: syntax error, unexpected END
```

I saw another post similar to this but they had close statements in their paragraph, but I don't here. This program is gotten from the textbook also so not sure why it isn't working for me.

Comment: The keywords are `END-READ` and `END-PERFORM` WITH A HYPHEN making each a single word, not separate words with a space. (But `STOP RUN` is two words, and so was `GO BACK` in older versions.) You _do_ have `CLOSE` statements, but they are not related at all to the problem.

Comment: ... updating to a more current version of GnuCOBOL is likely a good idea, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `END-PERFORM` with the **-** in it and not `END PERFORM`

Also it is `End-Read` not `end read`

See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6SG3_4.2.0/com.ibm.entcobol.doc_4.2/PGandLR/ref/rlpsperf.htm

Comment: Thanks that ended up getting it to run. Thanks for the link as well I was having issues finding much for Cobol.